# Format arguments as string

Tags: python, json, string, testing, pylance

I'm trying to pull in google service account details as an airflow variable and write this to file when running a KubernetesPodOperator. I'm currently trying to test this in pylance with a launch.json file as:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Pipeline",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "src",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "--assets_path", "s3://test/models/",
                "--folder_source", "s3://test/data/ner/qle_v1_with_postags/20210118_2100/",
                "--folder_destination", "/tmp/test/new",
                "--gcs_folder_destination", "gs://test/tmp/test/gcs",
                "--aws_region", "us-west-2",
                "--s3_endpoint", "s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                "--gcs_credentials", """"type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "test",
  "private_key_id": "b618cd07af66a9d57786af2575a23a3821728297",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nvsdjkfsdkjfbsajfklsdabfjubskfllbsdlafgbsafgjlsdabfjsadbfsjhda\njhdsgfhjegfsdfvgbdshjfgdshfgsdajhfsadkfh\nfgjkfdhgjkdfshgjkdfgl/dfkjsdhftkrshfbsjdkdffdnkljgfhdjfkghhdfkjlfghdskjsnhdfklhskjlfh/dfbhjsdfdgbhjsafghsdajkfgvshadjgfdggfhdfk\ndES0n7MPdwOW2sgXUKqAOGxZUiZvqGaY+rRBqmhIMYA1No4uou+nB1pyvR/tbGUn\nuPi6mnAeisUy6PKpbK/0m1rOdjta+xs2D3KSodw8FvZTZO8qhzP0k3tkYB/LMNdh\n079pZOV7AgMBAAECggEAFD7sMomWfpnmp2R1RKXe4fy4ISkFRLnyspMQhvQp/vQt\nb5TXmBIdXaA3m8kSZ/9ILHfMRPPfm06uvl5HDRAN6idQ+Jwez43ULJoa06wQizUS\nV\niYWzyLqVjBm/ztnhsPbazT9jz+CONsVgO2ViMm4BvBLv600JwivwFKxftJocQ5bi\ncLw3QBCdFgU64yfEdpYOCsNb\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "ml-storage@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "103551600936651887697",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/ml-storage%40test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}"""

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately i can't seem to convert the gcs_credentials into a string for testing.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. It looks like `gcs_credentials` is defining a multi-line string (by starting with triple quotes). How is this created, and how are you trying to load it?

Comment: I had added the triple quotes trying to import as string.

Comment: I am trying to test this in my launch. file for pylance in VsCode